# Efficient way to search for neighbouring tiles for each tile in a grid?

Tags: java

I have this A* search algorithm generating a path for one tile to another. The algorithm requires each tile to have a list of it's neighbours, and currently my code to search for all the neighbouring tiles for each looks like this:

```
/* PathTile is simply a class that holds an x,y coordinate, an unique ID and 
   an arraylist of neighbouring tiles. A method called intersect() allows me 
   to check if the tile's edge is touching other tiles. */

private void generatePathTileNeighbors()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pathTiles.size(); i++)
    {
        PathTile thisTile = pathTiles.get(i);

        for(int j = 0; j < pathTiles.size(); j++)
        {
            PathTile otherTile = pathTiles.get(j);
            if(!thisTile.uniqueID.equals(otherTile.uniqueID)){
                if(thisTile.intersect(otherTile)){
                    thisTile.addNeighbor(otherTile);
                    System.out.println(thisTile.uniqueID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure this is the absolute worst way to do it. For a grid of several thousands tiles, it takes minutes to load all the neighbouring tiles for each tile. What is a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks!

[image: Text](https://imgur.com/a/huhNBaW.jpg[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqxsl.png)) - What my grid looks like

Comment: Please add more details on class `PathTile`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a 2 dimensional array and the indexes as the point of finding neighbours.
For instance tiles[0][0] will have neighbours tiles[1][0],tiles[0][1], or even tiles[1][1] if you like.

Also, it would be better to addneighbour during the initialization of your tiles. therefore you get something like this

```
Tile tiles = new Tile[n][m];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<m ; j++){
     Tile tile  = new Tile();
     if(i-1 >= 0)
       tile.addNeighbour(tiles[i-1][j]);
     if(i+1 < n)
       tile.addNeighbour(tiles[i+1][j]);
     if(j-1 >= 0)
       tile.addNeighbour(tiles[i][j-1]);
     if(j+1 < m)
       tile.addNeighbour(tiles[i][j+1]);
     tiles[i][j] = tile;
   }
}
```